# Antonyms for "extempore" — speak without notes

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I am looking for antonyms for *extempore* in the context of "to speak extempore", i.e. speak without notes.

I am looking for something better than *prepared*.

Comment: What's wrong with *prepared*? What type of word would be "better"?

Comment: While you've stated that are looking for something better than 'prepared', I feel like this word is actually one of the best antonyms to extempore in the context of "speak without notes". It used at Toastmasters, for example, where the meetings would typically have the "impromptu" part and "prepared speeches" part.

Comment: @onomatomaniak - *Prepared* is not suitable for my requirements because it gives the impression that the speaker did some homework before the speech.

Comment: So you're looking for a word that means not practiced *and* not extemporaneous?

Comment: Not practiced and not impromptu? "Teleprompted"!

Comment: what is the opposite of this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use **rehearsed** or **scripted** as antonyms for *extempore*.

Examples:

> He gave a very scripted presentation, lacking all spontaneity.
>
> Although her interview seemed lively and extempore, it was in fact well rehearsed.

Answer (score 1):

What about *considered*, as in 'This is my considered judgment'?

Answer (score 1):

Noting that OP doesn't want the "exhaustively prepared" connotations of words like *rehearsed* or *scripted*, I would suggest **considered, measured,** or **careful** as ways of describing utterances which aren't carefully pre-planned, yet which suggest a level of forethought missing in *extempore*.